# Read a .sql file in R?

Tags: mysql, r, machine-learning

How do I read a very large amount of .sql file in R?
I don't have MySQL database I just have the raw data file? I tried using MS Access but couldn't able to find a solution.

Comment: Guess you need to install MySQL, import your file into the database and then you can connect to the DB from R with the `RMySQL` or `RODBC` packages. Don't think you can do anything without MySQL.

Comment: Is the file created by mysqldump? If yes, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738301/import-mysql-dump-into-r-without-requiring-mysql-server

Comment: There is an extended explanation in this page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042384/read-sql-function-in-r-using-r-as-an-sql-browser