# Import data from sql data base saved in .sql file from R

Tags: sql, r, phpmyadmin, readr

I have file `my_request_result.sql` which contains data (a lot of rows) exported from SQL phpmyadmin interface. The file contains only one table.

Now I want to read this data in R. Which libraries and commandands should I use to import data frame from this file.

I found out that `.sql` file extention is used also [to save SQL queries like "SELECT * FROM "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042384/read-sql-function-in-r-using-r-as-an-sql-browser). My file contains real data not queries.

Comment: Posssible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738301/import-mysql-dump-into-r-without-requiring-mysql-server

Comment: How does "my_request_result.sql" file look like? Could you add couple of example rows?

Comment: After reading the link provided of @Rohit I decided that export from SQL server to .csv files and than import it to R is the best way. Alternatively, one should use direct access to SQL server and query database